# Select two columns: multiple views, same condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I used multiple views to fetch two columns using subquery and union, I want to reduce this execution time.

```
select a.empid,empname from 
(select empid,empname from india_emp where deptno <> 10
union
select empid,empname from us_emp where deptno <> 10
union
select empid,empname from uk_emp where deptno <> 10
union
select empid,empname from uae_emp where deptno <> 10
union
select empid,empname from brazl_emp where deptno <> 10
union
select empid,empname from chine_emp where deptno <> 10
union
select empid,empname  from jpn_emp where deptno in (54,256,362,9879,24,46)
)a
where a.empid NOT IN(105,202,11,45,695,646,726,8465,965,56,646,689,446)
order by 2
```

Comment: Post up the execution plan

Comment: There isn't anything to go on. Are the views against the same base table? Are any of the individual queries slower than the others? Does the execution plan show a bottleneck? Is it using the appropriate indexes? Are statistics up to date? And so on... reducing the execution time is a very vague goal too.

Comment: i am new oracle dba and this is my first sql query optimize, i saw execution plan but i not understand really good, i only understand this above query used full scan table and i already created index in there main table and then create different many views after that i select his data but its execution time is 04.52 seconds and 225 records, i want to reduce this execution time but no idea how? so if you can tell me how to i reduce? give me way or any suggestion.. thanks in advance give to fast response...

Answer (score 0):

Change all your `Union` to `Union All`, which is less expensive.

Like this:

```
SELECT a.empid,empname FROM 
(SELECT empid,empname FROM india_emp WHERE deptno <> 10
UNION ALL
SELECT empid,empname FROM us_emp WHERE deptno <> 10
UNION ALL
SELECT empid,empname FROM uk_emp WHERE deptno <> 10
UNION ALL
SELECT empid,empname FROM uae_emp WHERE deptno <> 10
UNION ALL
SELECT empid,empname FROM brazl_emp WHERE deptno <> 10
UNION ALL
SELECT empid,empname FROM chine_emp WHERE deptno <> 10
UNION ALL
SELECT empid,empname  FROM jpn_emp WHERE deptno in (54,256,362,9879,24,46)
)a
WHERE a.empid NOT IN(105,202,11,45,695,646,726,8465,965,56,646,689,446)
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: i already put union to union all but not good works, its only 10 milliseconds reduce

Answer (score 0):

Can you try thin having empid filter inside the derived table?

```
select a.empid,empname from 
(select empid,empname from india_emp where deptno <> 10 and empid NOT IN(105,202,11,45,695,646,726,8465,965,56,646,689,446)
union
select empid,empname from us_emp where deptno <> 10 and empid NOT IN(105,202,11,45,695,646,726,8465,965,56,646,689,446)
union
select empid,empname from uk_emp where deptno <> 10 and empid NOT IN(105,202,11,45,695,646,726,8465,965,56,646,689,446)
union
select empid,empname from uae_emp where deptno <> 10 and empid NOT IN(105,202,11,45,695,646,726,8465,965,56,646,689,446)
union
select empid,empname from brazl_emp where deptno <> 10 and empid NOT IN(105,202,11,45,695,646,726,8465,965,56,646,689,446)
union
select empid,empname from chine_emp where deptno <> 10 and empid NOT IN(105,202,11,45,695,646,726,8465,965,56,646,689,446)
union
select empid,empname  from jpn_emp where deptno in (54,256,362,9879,24,46)
)a
where 
order by 2
```

Comment: Oracle will push the predicates automatically if it thinks it'll help.

Comment: i use but not works, and i used to like you said to write above type to query write its increase execution time..thank you suggestion but not worked..